# References for Boehm's algorithm of knot insertion?

Tags: spline, bspline

I'm implementing a program for rational b-spline motion, and am looking for some references about sing Bohm's algorithm for knot addition. Essentially, this is used to split the overall curve into multiple segments to avoid having to multiply B-spline functions (motion between points). I am having some difficulty finding references on this, and appreciate any information!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find plenty of references by googling "Boehm knot insertion". For example, the section 1.4.3 of this [article](http://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node18.html) describes Boehm's knot insertion algorithm.